# Add one result from one query and then second from another one

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop, phpmyadmin

I have Two MySQLi Queries and two result variables as below

1. `$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);`
2. `$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1);`

what I want to do is make  an array of all results , but the condition is it must contain one result from `$result` then the next one should be from `$result1` and next one from `$result` and so on until both variables have values.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $links[] = $row["url"];
    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
    {
        $links[] = $row1["ads_id"];
    }
}
```

Currently I have this this works like this , adds One value from `$results` next adds all values from `$results1` and next one by one adds all values from `$result` .

Can anybody help me out with this logic, I can not work out the logic for this thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this. It loops through `$result` and `$result1` at the same time, finishing up with any leftover rows from `$result1`:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $links[] = $row["url"];
    if ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
        $links[] = $row1["ads_id"];
}
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
    $links[] = $row1["ads_id"];
}
```

Comment: this will not work if both have over lets say more than 2 results right?

Comment: i need it work even if there are over 10 results on both, i need the array to have alternate values from both tables

Comment: Sure, it will work no matter how many results are in each set. The first while loop will process **all** the results from the first query and any matching results from the second query, and the second while loop will finish off any remaining results from the second query.